# Idiomatic verb when renouncing ones religion

Tags: single-word-requests

What's an idiomatic synonym for renounce in the context of renouncing ones religion?

Could also maybe be used as "I [X]'d the church"?

Comment: "Lost my faith" seems to be pretty common.

Comment: "Left the church" is a fairly common phrasing.  And of course there are terms such as "became disillusioned".

Comment: Not a verb, but you might be interested in the answers here: [Word for a person who loses or has lost faith?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156501/word-for-a-person-who-loses-or-has-lost-faith) Can you give more context for how you want to use this word, like an example sentence?

Comment: all helpful, thank you.

The sentences I had in mind would be of the form:
"He [X]'d his beliefs"
"She [X]'d the church"
"He [X]'d his/the religion"

Comment: It doesn’t necessarily require renunciation but “He [outgrew](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outgrow) his beliefs, his church, and his religion”  (“to stop being interested in or involved with [something or someone] because you have changed as you have grown older [, more mature, and wiser] ” M-W)

Answer (score 2):

***Abjure***, from Google https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=abjure (Does ELU frown on a Google definition?  This definition for abjure is good.)

> solemnly renounce (a belief, cause, or claim).
>
> "his refusal to abjure the Catholic faith"
>
> synonyms: renounce, relinquish, reject, forgo, disavow, abandon, deny,
>   repudiate, give up, wash one's hands of; eschew, abstain from, refrain
>   from; informal: kick, pack in; disaffirm; literary: forsake; formal:
>   forswear, abnegate
>
> "she has abjured the doctrines of her parents’ faith

Abjure is not idiomatic, but fits perfectly in your example sentences.  For an idiomatic phrase, try

***kick***, although this would apply more to habits than beliefs.  "He kicked all his daily rituals."

Answer (score 2):

One verb with that meaning is **apostasize**. Per [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apostatize):

> *apostasize*
>
> :  to commit apostasy

Where *apostasy* is defined in [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apostasy) as:

> *apostasy*
>
> :  renunciation of a religious faith